# Streamlit: Session_state() and Multiapp() - Navigation

Tags: python, streamlit

I wanted a layout where a user enters a file in "home page", and can perform visualization etc and again go back home add file to existing selected file.

Currently, when I go back home the selected file doesn't exists. Is there a way, where the file selected remains, while I navigation to other tab and come back home?

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround for using sessionstate for multipage functionality, which can be found in the discussion here - [Multi-page app with session state](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/multi-page-app-with-session-state/3074).

These are some useful gists

- [st_demo_settings.py](https://gist.github.com/okld/0aba4869ba6fdc8d49132e6974e2e662#gistcomment-3339119)
- [SessionStateManagement.py](https://github.com/gaurav-gunhawk/Python/blob/master/Streamlit/Streamlit-SessionStateManagement.py)

**[stateful_streamlit_enterprise](https://github.com/komodovaran/stateful_streamlit_enterprise)**

An example of how one can track state between multiple pages in Streamlit without reloading pages.

In addition to this, it also demonstrates Mypy type-safety with classes, decorators, inheritance, wrapping Streamlit, etc.

Instead of using self, you'll find that all data lives in the session sess.

Tested on Python 3.7 and Streamlit 0.73.

Comment: are all these hacks still necessary with the latest release of streamlit?